# DevExpress MVC control bind to upshot datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, upshot

I would like to know if its possible to use the DevExpress MVC controls with Upshot and knockout

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is easy to do. DevExpress developed their DXtreme product to interface with the server using Knockout and Upshot. The product is good, but is missing the GridView control, so we aren't able to use it.

If you have a simple form, you could get this to work by using the SetValue() and GetValue() properties on all of the controls. So, instead of using the Knockout data-bind behavior, you could use the normal DevExpress binding, then when you want to save with Ajax you can create a class that takes the values from the forms and sends them back to the server. But that really defeats the purpose of using Knockout for the UI.